# Spreadsheet Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can we create a spreadsheet form and open it when the user when user logs in ?

I need a form which will record the attendance of the employee when He/She logs in . Also i would like to validate the code so that it must be shown only at first login.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking.. but from the little I got, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Henrique. I have modified the question to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do is not possible unless you were to authenticate users yourself, then pass that along to google. Nonetheless, you would still have to train your users to login on your special page, and they could circumvent the form by logging into google directly. If you are looking for login history, then the reporting API, Domain Management Panel or FlashPanel might provide the kind of report for which you search.

Comment: Thanks fooby for the advice.